# Mother board plugs not working since Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I just updated my computer from ubuntu 17.04 to ubuntu 17.10 and since then,It seems my intel cpu graphics stopped working.

I currently have a HP tower with a AMD graphic card, but i have 3 screens and only two ports available on my graphic card (HDMI and DVI) so i use one of the port(DVI) on the motherboard for my third screen and it worked fine until I updated ubuntu to 17.10 version this morning.

For now, i've tried updating the driver using intel graphic update tool by tricking it into thinking i was using Ubuntu17.04. did not work

I've tried bringing back lightdm as display manager, did not work either.

I'm kind of out of options, a little help would be nice :)

Thanks!